# Changing HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE

Tags: firefox, php, language, http

Is it possible to change `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE`?

I'm using Firefox.

Answer (score 13):

Also you can go to about:config in the address bar and modify the preference

`intl.accept_languages`

The format is comma-separated list of [language tags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IETF_language_tag). e.g.:

en-us, en-gb, en, es

with the languages listed in decreasing order of preference.

Answer (score 7):

> Tools -> Options -> Content ->
>   Languages -> Select a language to add

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can change the list of preferred languages in Firefox's Settings.

Mozilla Forums: [How to change the default language in Firefox](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=880485)