# How Do I Add a Custom Language in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, localization, i18n

Firefox has a list of built-in languages that are used to set the HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE header.  How do I add a custom one that's not on the list?

Comment: Related: [List at mozilla.org with installers for ***Firefox in all the languages***](https://www.mozilla.org/da/firefox/all/) (including British English).,

Answer (score 6):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
Tools -> Options -> Content ->  Languages -> Select a language to add
```

It's from a [similar post](https://superuser.com/questions/131968/changing-http-accept-language).

**EDIT:**

As far as I can tell, this GUI option just changes the preference "intl.accept_languages" in about:config. You could edit this yourself to change it to a custom value. I'm not sure if you can put language files somewhere to get a custom language to work or not.

Comment: How do you add an unlisted language?

Comment: @MItch I just typed in the two letter code for the language and it worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `about:config` to edit the list of language codes:

Enter `about:config` into address field, find the setting `intl.accept_languages`. Its value is the list of language codes to send as `Accept-Language` HTTP header. The list is comma-separated in descending priority. You can enter any code you like; the codes will even be displayed in the standard pref dialog (see mouche's answer), where you can delete them later (just not add them).

As an aside: Why do you need this? I have never encountered a website that supports more than the (extensive) set of standard tags as defined in ISO-639. Which special tags do you want to use, and why?

Comment: It can be needed for customized, non-standard locales, like "en_Pirate", if you want the browser to select them without an application level override.

Answer (score -2):

Firefox has a section on their website where you can download and add custom languages to your Firefox:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/browse/type:3

Comment: How do you add an unlisted language?

Comment: -1 No, that's not for adding languages to the list of accepted languages, that's for changing the language of Firefox' UI.